# Formatting & Manipulation database data for display in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, json, uitableview

I am working on an application to display user information stored in a database in an iOS app in a table view. Currently i am logging all information from the server to the console (in the debug area) using

```
NSLog(@"user information is as follows:  %@", JSON);
```

Which provides output as such:

```
{ email = “andrew.smith19381223@gmail.com”;
    “first_name” = Andrew;
    “Last_name” = Smith 
    id = 12
    user_info=    (
                {
            "Room" = "Lab 2";
            DayNumber = 1;
       lesson = 2;
            id = 12;
            Instructor = "MR BEERRY";
            Group_No = 7;
        },
                {
            "class_room" = "S GEO";
            DayNumber = 1;
            lesson = 2;
            id = 12;
            teacher = "Mr RING";
            Group_No  = 7;
        },
```

...

I would like to use this information in table view columns and as parameters (for eg. the day no.) for the tableview.How should i store/format this information in my iOS application  so it can be used for a tableview.I have been googleing for a while without luck :(

Comment: just store json string to NSDictionary then use it for tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JSON parser (e.g. `NSJSONSerialization`) in order to parse the JSON text and create a *representation*. The generic representation is a hierarchy of Foundation objects. In your case, the root element is a *JSON Object* which maps to a `NSDictionary` in the representation. That dictionary contains the keys `@"email"`, `@"first_name"`, `@"Last_name"`, `@"id"`, `@"user_info"`, etc. You can access the corresponding value for a key with the method `-objectForKey:` which you should be familiar with.

The corresponding object for key `@"user_info"` is a `NSArray`, whose elements are objects of kind `NSDictionary`.

And so force.

Since the JSON is a dynamic data structure you need some knowledge in the application what that JSON actually shall be and what you expect when you receive that. That is, you may expect a certain structure and keys and certain values. In order to make your live easier, you may use that representation to *initialize* your "custom model" - which has properties and behavior as you require.

Once you have your model, display it as usual in a `UITable` view.